# Validate Map option not showing in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xslt, visual-studio-2015, azure-logic-apps, biztalk-mapper

I want to validate .btm map and want to generate xslt file but as mentioned in the following article: [How to Configure Map Validation and Test Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-configure-map-validation-and-test-parameters)

The "**Validate Map**" option not showing by doing a right click on .btm file as seen in the Screenshot below.

Any solution?

[image: Screenshot1]

Comment: Do you have a BizTalk Server license?

Comment: No. It's a developer edition.

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual studio tools from your BizTalk installer

[image]

After adding this option, make sure you restart your visual studio and build your project. You should able to validate your map.

[image]